# Compiler directives mismatch

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I have an application which is supposed to run on MACOS and IOS.
Somehow both codes are executed when compiling for IOS and it drives me crazy:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin

  {$IfDef MacOs}
  ShowMessage('MACOS');
  {$Endif}

  {$IfDef IOS}
  ShowMessage('IOS');
  {$Endif}

end;
```

When running on any IOS device, both of the messages are displayed.

In other words, IOS application execute any codes defined for MACOS

Any idea?

Comment: Swell! Another addition to the XE7 complications, like we don't have enough.
Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design, as you can see in [Conditional Compilation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Conditional_compilation_%28Delphi%29) in the documentation.

If you want to differentiate between iOS and OSX, use the `MACOS` (OSX) and `CPUARM` (IOS) predefined constants instead, both of which are listed in the *platform* section of the documentation I linked above.

As Remy Lebeau points out in his comment below, this isn't effective when running under the iOS simulator. In order to properly differentiate between the two, you need to use `{$IF defined(MACOS) and not defined(IOS)}`.

Comment: `MACOS` is also defined in the iOS simulator but `CPUARM` is not. So, to differentiate between OSX and iOS, you need `{$IF defined(MACOS) and not defined(IOS)}`.  And if you need the code to compile in FPC, it gets more complicated because DCC and FPC use different defines for OSX.